# I need to understand this C code

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C so I need someone who can explain the following program which should convert celsius to fahrenheit and viceversa. Step by Step.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TF2TC

     main() {
     double tc, tf, offset, conv;

     offset = 32.;

#ifdef TF2TC
     conv = 5. / 9.;
     printf("Fahrenheit Value= ");
     scanf("%lf",&tf);
     tc = (tf - offset) * conv;
     printf("celsius value= %f\n",tc);
#endif
#ifndef TF2TC
     conv = 9. / 5.;
     printf("celsius value= ");
     scanf("%lf",&tc);
     tf = tc * conv + offset;
     printf("fahrenheit value= %f\n",tf);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Where do people come up with programs like these, when setting out to learn C? It's not ... the best learning program I can imagine. Just read K&R, or some other sensible book. :)

Comment: the posted code does not compile cleanly.   Always enable all warnings when compiling.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  Then fix the warnings.    Note: the declaration for the main() function always returns an 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double tc, tf, offset, conv; // --> declaring 4 doubles

     offset = 32.; // --> assigning 32.0 to offset

#ifdef TF2TC // --> if the macro TF2TC was defined do this:
     conv = 5. / 9.; // --> assigning 5. / 9. to conv
     printf("Fahrenheit Value= "); // --> printing "Fahrenheit Value= "
     scanf("%lf",&tf); // --> scanning user input and storing it in tf
     tc = (tf - offset) * conv; // --> assigning (tf - offset) * conv to tc
     printf("celsius value= %f\n",tc); // --> printing "celsius value= {value of tc}"
#endif
#ifndef TF2TC // --> if the macro TF2TC wasn't defined do this:
     conv = 9. / 5.; // --> assigning 5. / 9. to conv
     printf("celsius value= "); // --> printing "celsius value= "
     scanf("%lf",&tc); // --> scanning user input and storing it in tf
     tf = tc * conv + offset; // assigning tc * conv + offset to tf
     printf("fahrenheit value= %f\n",tf); // --> printing "fahrenheit value= {value of tf} "
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the major concepts of the posted code.

(A) if the `TF2TC` macro is defined, then compile the code to convert a user input from Fahrenheit to Celsius .

(B) If the `TF2TC` macro is not defined, then compile the code to convert a user input from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

In the posted code, the `TF2TC` macro is defined, by: `#define TF2TC` so the (A) code is compiled and the other block of code is ignored.